# How to write a mutlicolumn file in Python?

Tags: python, file-io

I want to go through a list of complex numbers and write the real part as rows in a file. The following code does not make the job

```
for (column1, column2) in zip(t_inter, tp_inter):
    file_t.write("%s\t\n" % column1.real)
    file_tp.write("%s\t\n" % column2.real)
```

What's wrong? I guess the `\n` command goes to a new line but if I remove it, all data are written in a single line. The main issue is that I don't now a priori the number of elements in the t_inter and tp_inter lists, usually between 2 and 20 max. Therefore is there any command that writes rows without specifying the number of elements through `%/s\t`? At last, I want to add a constant as a first column, how to do it?

Comment: [`csv.writer`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) is your friend.

Comment: Are you trying to write both columns into the same file? If so, why are you using two different file objects? If not, what else should there be in the files besides the single column you're now writing?

Comment: No actually I want to write many (I don't know a priori how many) columns into two files. Therefore I go through the lists t_inter and tp_inter with column1 and column2 and at every indentation I want to write the elements as rows in different files. The thing is %s\t is the good format but it writes everything on a single row. If I add \n I have a single column which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0):

i think `pprint` is your way:

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.__doc__
"Support to pretty-print lists, tuples, & dictionaries recursively.\n\nVery simp
le, but useful, especially in debugging data structures.\n\nClasses\n-------\n\n
PrettyPrinter()\n    Handle pretty-printing operations onto a stream using a con
figured\n    set of formatting parameters.\n\nFunctions\n---------\n\npformat()\
n    Format a Python object into a pretty-printed representation.\n\npprint()\n
   Pretty-print a Python object to a stream [default is sys.stdout].\n\nsaferepr
()\n    Generate a 'standard' repr()-like value, but protect against recursive\n
    data structures.\n\n"
>>>
```